# Format Web Service Data into a Table

Tags: powerbi, m

I am having issues needed to make a table of 3 columns from a REST API response  using Power Query M language.

Below is my code ( at the end of which my table 'newTable' still remains empty

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://admcorpdev.service-now.com/api/now/stats/incident?sysparm_query=active%3Dtrue%5EpriorityIN1%2C2&sysparm_count=true&sysparm_group_by=caller_id.location.u_region%2Cpriority")),
    result = Table.FromRecords(Source[result]),
    newTable = #table(
        {
            "Priority",  
            "Region",
            "Count"   
        },
        {}
    ),
    TableSource = Table.Buffer(result),
    data = List.Generate( 
        () => [x=0],
        each [x]<= Table.RowCount(result),
        each [ 
            //Generate a new Table and append fields into it
            newTable = Table.InsertRows(newTable,1,{[Priority = "2", Region ="NA",Count = "56"]}),
            x=[x]+1] 
    )
in
    newTable
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the code

Comment: Try changing the last lines from `in newTable` to `in data` and see if you get required output. Power Query uses lazy evaluation, so only expressions required by `newTable` will be evaluated.

Comment: Also, Power Query can handle the URL query string for you. Just so you know, you could change your first line to: `Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://admcorpdev.service-now.com/api/now/stats/incident", [Query=[sysparm_query="active=true^priorityIN1,2", sysparm_count="true", sysparm_group_by="caller_id.location.u_region,priority"]])),`. I can't really post an answer as the I can't access the URL (due to authentication/credential issues) and because you haven't explained what your expected output is.